# template tag and permissions not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-permissions

I cannot get permissions to work in django templates that are loaded via the use of the `inclusion_tag`.

```
{% if perms.myapp.foo %}
     <p>In lookup works, too.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The above works fine in my "main" template that is called from my view.

However if i then use that same code in an `inclusion_tag` template it doesn't work. I thought maybe that was because the tags are not passed `request`?

The django doco [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions) says that a users permissions are stored in the template variable `{{ perms }}`. Is this not being made available to custom tags? I am assuming that this *should* work, can't imagine why it would be by design?

Users with 'superuser' status also fail, which makes sense if the `{{ perms }}` is missing.

I looked into `takes_context` [doco link here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) but haven't been able to make that work. Not sure if thats taking me down the wrong path?

======== Updated ==============================

- Figured it out, have moved my update into an 'Answer' below.

Comment: You should use `takes_context` so that you can access `perms`. Please show your inclusion tag.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, i figured it out with your nudge in the right direction and added the detail to my question above. Feel free to respond with an 'Answer' and i can mark it accepted.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I could add an answer, but it would be better if you added your solution above as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question as suggested.

So I investigated the 'takes_context' further as suggested by user 'alasdair'. I got it working as a result. Here is what I found.

Inside `myapp-tags.py`:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('templatefilename.html', takes_context=True)
def show_mycustomtag(context, start_date, end_date):

 #your code here 

return {
    'start_date': start_date,
    'end_date': end_date,

    'perms': context['perms']
}
```

- You must add `takes_context=True` when registering the inclusion tag.
- You can then add whatever `context` variables you want passed from the 'main' template to the 'custom tag' in `return`. In my case, I needs the `perms` variable passed through.
- Once i did the above, I could do the usual `{% if perms.myapp.foo %}` etc code in my tag template :)

It is explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) in the Django doco however I got a bit confused as I was mixing context variables with tag specific ones but as you can see from the above, thats not a problem!

Comment: This has stopped working in Django 1.10. In Django 1.9 it worked fine. Now, context dictionary does not have 'request' or 'perms' keys. Does anyone know how to do it in 1.10?